# Показать элемент, если на странице присутствует элемент с определенным ID/Class (Slick Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider-slick.js

стала необходима задача отобразить блок, только после прокрутки до последнего слайда SLick Slider, к сожалению дизайнер слабо понимает основы html/css и рисует вот таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге имеем - слайдер с overflow:hidden и невозможностью расположить кнопки за слайдером.
Отсюда вытекает вопрос - возможно ли показать кнопки (элемент) после прокрутки к последнему слайду или же показать их, когда элемент с определенным id/class в поле зрения, и убрать кнопки, если не в поле зрения.

Comment: Intersection Observer API можешь попробовать..

Comment: Я щас вообще не понял проблемы с отобржением. Вы знаете кол-во слайдов, вы можете слушать переключение слайдов и при каждом переключении увиличивать счётчик и проверять достигли ли вы конца? Я не уверен, но предполагаю что этой либы должно быть отдельное событие при достижени конца не бесконечного слайдера